# rails validation error nested object undefined method... for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I've made a scheduling app where people are assigned to rooms each day.  On Thursdays someone must be assigned for 'pager pickup' and I'm having problems with the validation to check for that.

### Model

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :rooms
  ...
  validate :thursday_schedule_must_have_pager_pickup
  ...

  def add_rooms
    return unless self.rooms.count == 0                           
    n = 1
    tomorrow = DateTime.tomorrow                                  
    Schedule.site_list.each do |site|                             
      Schedule.const_get(site).each do |room|                     
        self.rooms.build(order: n,                                
                      site: site.to_s,                         
                      name: room,
                      start_hour: get_start_hour(tomorrow),    
                      start_minute: get_start_minute(tomorrow, site.to_s))                   
        n += 1                                                    
      end
    end
    self.add_pager_pickup(n, tomorrow) if true # self.for_thursday?
    self.add_today_call_data(n) if no_call_data                   
  end
...
def add_pager_pickup(order, tomorrow)
  self.rooms.build(order: order,
      site: "TSH",
      name: "Pager Pickup",
      start_hour: 7,
      start_minute: get_start_minute(tomorrow, "TSH"))
  end
end

class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :schedule
  ...
end
```

The code I'd like to write is:

```
def thursday_schedule_needs_pager_pickup
  if self.for_thursday? && self.rooms.where(name: "Pager Pickup").first.initials.blank?
    errors.add(:rooms, "'Pager Pickup' can't be empty.  Select '-- late start' if no one should come in early to pick up pager.")
  end
end
```

That generates the following errors:

```
NoMethodError in SchedulesController#create
undefined method `initials' for nil:NilClass
```

By adding the "Pager Pickup" room to the schedule last I can hack a validation with the following code:

```
... self.rooms.last.initials.blank?
```

But that's brittle and preventing me from adding a 2nd, optional, pager pickup person, "2nd Pager Pickup", after the first.

Per Julien's points:

### Schedule Controller

```
class SchedulesController < ApplicationController 
...
  def new
    s = current_user.schedules.new
    s.add_rooms
    @schedule = s
  end

  def create 
    @schedule = current_user.schedules.build(schedule_params)
    if @schedule.save 
      flash.now[:success] = "Draft Schedule Saved! Now Confirm or Edit."
      render :show
    else
    render :new
  end
...
end
```

Anyone have any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a room record with the name *Pager Pickup*?

Comment: Good question, @Pavan.  Yes, I'm pretty confident I've been careful to make sure that a typo like a spelling or case error isn't preventing a room named "Pager Pickup" from existing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading your code correctly, you have an unsaved object and you're trying to run this validation on it:

```
self.rooms.where(name: "Pager Pickup").first.initials.blank?
```

The problem with this approach is that `.where` on association will run a database query (or to be specific, it'd run the query if your objects were saved, but will do nothing for unsaved relations). This won't work for you, you haven't saved anything yet, you have to operate on objects in memory. If you change that line to:

```
self.rooms.detect {|r| r.name == "Pager Pickup" }.initials.blank?
```

it **should** work but it is still prone to errors if you simply leave it in your model, as in another context there might not be a room with that name and `.initials` will still be called on `nil`. I'd suggest you move such logic to factory objects, where you can strictly tie your validations to the context.

In order to fully understand the concept, you may run this in `rails console`:

```
s = Schedule.new
# => #<Schedule id: nil>
s.rooms << Room.new(foo: "bar")
# => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Room id: nil, schedule_id: nil, foo: "bar">]>
s.rooms.where(foo: "bar")
# => #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>
s.rooms.detect { |r| r.foo == "bar" }  
# => #<Room id: nil, schedule_id: nil, foo: "bar">
```

**Note**: Your "hack" with `.last` worked because it operated on an array, not an ActiveRecord::Relation.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you!  Problem solved.  Thought that the issue lay with whether `where` was able to act on object not yet saved to database but didn't know about detect and select.  Very grateful.  Tried to award +50 points but SO says must wait 22 hours.... Will do so when able, though.

Answer (score 2):

The problem that you are facing is that you are trying to do a query on a model that is not yet saved into the database. It does not have an `id` and the associated models `rooms` do not yet have an `id` themselves either.

Your validation throws an error because `.where` calls the database and it can't find the models, as they currently live only in memory.

```
self.rooms.where(name: "Pager Pickup").first.initials.blank?
```

However, you have the information on both models to do the validation correctly, you are just looking for it in the wrong place.

If you debug your app so that your instance of `Schedule` is built (not saved yet) and you add some `rooms` to it (not yet saved either), you will see the following behavior:

```
@schedule.rooms.length # It will be some value bigger than 0

@schedule.rooms.count # It will be zero
```

Why? Because `.length` works on the object as an array and `.count` searches for it in the database. As I mentioned before, your models do not exist on the DB so it wont find them, but they are in memory so you can measure the `length` of it.

The change you need to do in this problem is to imitate what `.where` does but in memory, with a simple `.select`:

```
self.rooms.select { |r| r.name == 'Pager Pickup' }.first.initials.blank?
```

That is the only change you need to do, but you should understand why.

Comment: `.detect { }` is a bit nicer than `.select { }.first`, but still a valid answer.

Comment: This works and thank you for your answer and explanation.  Selected @MarcinKołodziej because submitted a couple minutes before yours....  Very grateful, though.

Comment: Yeah I noticed the difference in time. We're glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so first of all

```
self.rooms.where(name: "Pager Pickup")
```

is potentially going to return multiple objects so it doesn't give you a `Room` object but probably an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object so you would need to add something like `.first` before `.initials` to get a `Room` like so:

```
self.rooms.where(name: "Pager Pickup").first.initials.blank?
```

But anyway the error states that it is not finding anything so it seems that at the time of validation the `rooms` relationship for this schedule doesn't exist or is "empty" since it is claiming `nil` is returned from that query instead of an empty array so i'm guessing that your validation occurs before the room is actually created/saved.

Maybe show us the `create` action of the `SchedulesController` to see if something is wrong there.

**UPDATE**

After seeing your extra code, the problem is that you are calling add_rooms to a different schedule object than the one you are creating, I'm guessing your are on the impression that instance variables (variables starting with `@`) are persisted between requests but they are not, so the `@schedule` object in your `create` action is not the same one as in your `new` action therefore it doesn't have any rooms yet, update your `create` action to populate the rooms of that object doing something like this:

```
  def create 
    @schedule = current_user.schedules.build(schedule_params)
    @schedule.add_rooms    # <-- Add this line
    if @schedule.save 
      flash.now[:success] = "Draft Schedule Saved! Now Confirm or Edit."
      render :show
    else
    render :new
  end
```

Comment: Thanks, @Julien.  Added the .first and as you predicted it still doesn't work.  I edited my answer to include the SchedulesController#Create and other methods in the Schedule Model that may include my error.  Thanks so much for your insight.

Comment: when is `add_rooms` called? i don't see it in the `create` action and i'm guessing its not in the `schedule_params` so where do you call it?

Comment: `add_rooms` is called in the SchedulesController#New action.  I added it.

Comment: well there's your problem, you are adding the rooms on a different schedule object than the one you are creating, you need to add the rooms to your `@schedule` object in the `create` action before calling `save` on it.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include some details regarding my previous comment.

Comment: Thank you for your continued interest in my problem, @Julien.  Unfortunately your suggestion does not work.  Note that without the `thursday_schedule_needs_pager_pickup` validation the site works fine -- rooms added appropriately -- but someone can make a Thursday schedule without assigning someone to pager pickup.  Adding `add_rooms` where you do (after they've already been added in the `new` action and passed along as `schedule_parems`) adds additional duplicate rooms which then attempted to be saved.  As noted, a hack validation checking last room initials works but is brittle.

Comment: ok so add the rest of the code that is missing including the form since it seems that form is sending back the rooms created in the `new` action, add also the `schedule_params` and anything else you might think is necessary so that i can reproduce your problem and i'll debug it locally, saves us from further guess work.